# How do I log into a local server using the XMPP protocol? (iPhone SDK) 

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0, ios4

How do I log into a local server using the XMPP protocol? (iPhone SDK)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to logning local sever then you just but your sever ip address and port no.
You would be a add ip address like this `[xmppStream setHostName:@"10.0.1.98"];` in connect method.

Thanks 
Anurag